# Google sign in using Xamarin forms error 400 redirect_uri_missmatch

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-oauth

I have followed the following guide for google sign in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth and for reference I took this example https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/OAuthNativeFlow/.

As per the steps I created Android and iOS client ID but for android I didnt get any redirect URL option.

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static string AppName = "TestingLogin";

    // OAuth
    // For Google login, configure at https://console.developers.google.com/
    public static string iOSClientId = "clientID";
    public static string AndroidClientId = "clientID";

    // These values do not need changing
    public static string Scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
    public static string AuthorizeUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
    public static string AccessTokenUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    public static string UserInfoUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";

    // Set these to reversed iOS/Android client ids, with :/oauth2redirect appended
    public static string iOSRedirectUrl = "<insert IOS redirect URL here>:/oauth2redirect";
    public static string AndroidRedirectUrl = "http://weblogin.bestokleen.com/googleindex.aspx:/oauth2redirect";
}
```

please check the image for reference. I added my android client ID but I couldnt find any redirect url for android on console.developers.google.com. So i created a web client and registered a redirect url which is working in web browser so I used that particular redirect URL in my project But got same error.

Now I tried placing Web Client ID and redirectURL instead of Android cliend ID but still getting the same error as shown in the pic.

[image: The error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first link:

> Therefore, a complete example of a redirect URL utilizing a custom URL scheme is `com.googleusercontent.apps.<client ID>:/oauth2redirect`

Anyway, the Android Client ID looks like `<What I called Client ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com`. So chances might be, that you'll succeed by using the reversed Android Client ID for the redirect URL.

Anyway, I succeeded using `<my package name>:/oauth2redirect` (something like `com.yourcompany.yourapp:/oauth2redirect`) both for Android and iOS, but don't ask me if there have been any further steps involved.

**EDIT**

From the first link, too ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth#android))

> The DataSchemes property of the IntentFilter must be set to the reversed client identifier that's obtained from the Android client id for the project on Google API Console.

That supports my presumption made upon the other information.